# Receiving NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION as connected while changing network

Tags: android, networking, broadcastreceiver, wifi, broadcast

**Problem:**

I'm developing an Android application that needs to switch between different Wi-Fi networks. When the user decides to connect to another network, my app has to wait until the connection is completed, so I need to know when that happens.

To achieve that I registered a BroadcastReceiver which only receives NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION. When a broadcast is received, I get the NetworkInfo extra and check if it is connected.

I tested this on one Android 5.0 device and it worked. However, when I tested on another device, with Android 5.1, the app didn't wait until the connection was completed. That happened because a broadcast was received immediately after I switched into another network, and the NetworkInfo object indicated network connected.

Why was that supposed to happen?

**Minimal working example:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            Log.i("Wi-Fi network state", info.getDetailedState().toString());
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

While running this program, I switched manually to another network. Here's the NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION events printed in the log thereafter:

```
02-03 17:25:23.786 I/Wi-Fi network state: CONNECTED       <-- Why? I'm disconnecting :(
02-03 17:25:23.794 I/Wi-Fi network state: DISCONNECTED
02-03 17:25:23.800 I/Wi-Fi network state: DISCONNECTED
02-03 17:25:23.898 I/Wi-Fi network state: DISCONNECTED
02-03 17:25:23.941 I/Wi-Fi network state: DISCONNECTED
02-03 17:25:23.944 I/Wi-Fi network state: CONNECTING
02-03 17:25:23.955 I/Wi-Fi network state: CONNECTING
02-03 17:25:26.205 I/Wi-Fi network state: AUTHENTICATING
02-03 17:25:26.210 I/Wi-Fi network state: OBTAINING_IPADDR
02-03 17:25:26.214 I/Wi-Fi network state: OBTAINING_IPADDR
02-03 17:25:26.219 I/Wi-Fi network state: CONNECTING
02-03 17:25:26.221 I/Wi-Fi network state: OBTAINING_IPADDR
02-03 17:25:28.292 I/Wi-Fi network state: CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK
02-03 17:25:28.297 I/Wi-Fi network state: CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK
02-03 17:25:28.304 I/Wi-Fi network state: CONNECTED
02-03 17:25:28.312 I/Wi-Fi network state: CONNECTED
02-03 17:30:32.400 I/Wi-Fi network state: CONNECTED
```

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

I was able to solve the problem using a simple trick: every time I have to switch into another Wi-Fi network, I know its ID. So I know the connection is completed when the broadcast is received, the network state is connected, AND the current network has the expected ID. Like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

    if (info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        if (wifiManager == null) return;

        WifiInfo connection = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

        if (connection != null && connection.getNetworkId() == expectedId) {
            // Connection complete!
        }
    }
}
```

Still, the question remains. Why should my app receive a broadcast indicating network CONNECTED when in fact I was disconnecting?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking the connection from the `Intent`, Try writing an external class that checks the connection from the current context.

```
/*
 * True if network available else FALSE
 */
public static boolean isNetwork(Context mContext) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
}
```

and from your `BroadcastReceiver` try calling the above method to determine the availability of the `INTERNET`.

Comment: I'm testing your solution, seems promising. However, the method `getAllNetworkInfo()` in ConnectivityManager is deprecated.

Comment: I used the class you posted, but all the calls to `isConnectingToInternet()` returned false. I tried some variations, avoiding the deprecated methods, but with no success whatsoever. Anyway, thanks for helping!

Comment: @Milack : I've changed the code, please check the edited answer.

Comment: Strange. In the first broadcast, the `activeNetwork` info object is connected, fine. But in the last broadcast, when the new connection is supposedly completed, the `activeNetwork`  is null, so the funcion `isNetwork(context)` returns false.